# Node js: Automated Broadcast, facebook messenger

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, facebook-messenger

I am writing a messenger bot with node js express. I want to broadcast daily messages to my users. To do that, I need to use the following post requests:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{    
  "messages":[
    <MESSAGE_OBJECT>
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/message_creatives?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>>"
```

This one outputs a message_creative_id and is followed by the following:

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{    
  "message_creative_id": <MESSAGE_CREATIVE_ID>,
  "notification_type": "<REGULAR | SILENT_PUSH | NO_PUSH>",
  "messaging_type": "MESSAGE_TAG",
  "tag": "NON_PROMOTIONAL_SUBSCRIPTION"
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/broadcast_messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

Is there any way to automatically send the requests at a preset time?

Edit: The post needs to be repeated daily and the a different message will sent. The messages will be predetermined and the admin should not have to change it through the code.

Edit2: I also plan on automating it to a degree so that non-technical admins can add the messages. i.e. they will just enter the time and message and some script will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to add `"schedule_time": "<ISO-8601_OR_UNIX_TIMESTAMP>"` parameter to your existing request body of `/broadcast_messages` endpoint, for more info please refer to [Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/broadcast-messages/#scheduling).

Comment: Will it be repeated each day? Also, what if I want to change the message every time?

Comment: it will not, you'll have to add multiple scheduled broadcasts for both repetition and different times.

Comment: correction, not  different times, meant to say  different messages.

Comment: Is there any way to embed that in my code instead of manually sending a request for each message?

Comment: even if you use something like a cron scheduler in your end it will not change the fact you will need to send a separate request each time, for the moment since Facebook does not have a bulk scheduling mechanism, you will pretty much have to use separate request for each.

Comment: Will it be possible to add a separate script which takes user input and makes the requests?

Comment: Yes, you can create script that will take inputs as command line arguments, or you can write a node rest api that handles the same request.